# How to Trigger a pull request using script or pipeline once build is successful from azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pull-request, branching-and-merging

I have a requirement. Whether it is possible or not I don't know
Requirement: I have three branches 1. Master, 2. Dev, 3. Test.
Here every time new code is committed to dev or test and we create a build to execute the code. Now the requirement is I don't want to merge the code to Master branches unless build is success for master. When build is successful then only PR will be triggered and code will be merged to Master Branch.

Master build ---> Success ----> Then merge code with Master Branch.
Is this possible, without merging the new code into main branch, how can we test the new code from master branch in the build. And if that build is success then only PR has to take place and merge the code in master branch.

Comment: Use a branch policy.

Comment: I know branch policy. But requirement is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My requirement is Once the normal build is success then only PR has to be triggered and merge the code with master branch. Can this be achievable with powershell/bash script that can trigger a PR from pipeline (Build)

I'm pretty sure what you are looking for is branch polices [Build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation) instead of trigger a PR from pipeline.

You may not fully understand the logic of Build validation and PR.

What you want to achieve is to protect the master and **not** merge the PR on the branch to the master until the build verification success.

So, the key point is to **verify the code after the PR merge**, instead of triggering the PR after the build is completed. Otherwise, your build will always be the code on the master before the merge, and this verification will be meaningless.

Adding the Build validation on the master branch, which will trigger the build pipeline when we create a pull request. When we create a PR, it will create a temp commit to save the merged code and build pipeline will checkout this new temp commit to build. If build successful, then we could complete the PR, otherwise, we could not complete the PR, the master code would not be updated.

That should be what you want.

Comment: Yes. I want that one only what you said above..====>   Adding the Build validation on the master branch, which will trigger the build pipeline when we create a pull request. When we create a PR, it will create a temp commit to save the merged code and build pipeline will checkout this new temp commit to build. If build successful, then we could complete the PR, otherwise, we could not complete the PR, the master code would not be updated.  @Leo

Comment: @RajaShekar, So, what is your problem now? Build validation should be work for you.

Comment: Ok I will check this flow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps uses branch polices to achieve this which you can read about [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation)

Comment: I know branch policy. Requirement is different. I need to create a build on master branch without pushing the New code to master. Once the build is success then, PR has to be create for the master.  Using branch policy PR creates build and next auto complete merge will happen.  Lets consider  a case. I have dev, test and master. Both new code in dev and test are working fine. But when i merge it with master not working. Again we have take back the code. Instead before merging to master if we check in master whether build work or not. If it work then only we will push to master. Is it possible?

Comment: @RajaShekar I don't understand why a branch policy wouldn't work for this scenario.

Comment: @RajaShekar the code would only auto complete a merge if set up to do so and can be blocked by other branch policies. The only reason this wouldn't work is if the build effected the environment that is built off master but then the requirement is impossible. Can you please explain how build validation is not meeting your requirements as what you have described is build validation!

Comment: @RajaShekar, The build validation should work for your situation. When you create the PR (will create a new commit ID with new code), which will trigger the build validation, the build will check code after the merged, if it success, it will merge, if not, will not merge.

Comment: My requirement is Once the normal build is success then only PR has to be triggered and merge the code with master branch. Can this be achievable with powershell/bash script  that can trigger a PR from pipeline (Build)